# Is it possible to catch specific Exceptions in Azure Durable Functions Orchestator?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions, orchestration

I am struggling to catch specific Exceptions in the durable function orchestrator. If a raise an inbuilt or custom exception it won't be caught. e.g if i rasie TypeError in the durable function activty, it won't be able to be caught in the try and except statement in the orchestrator.

Function Activity:

```
import requests
import logging
from shared_code.custom_exceptions import *
        
    
def main(name: dict) -> str:
    raise TypeError()
```

Orchestrator Function:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as df


def orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
    json_body = context.get_input()

    try:
        yield context.call_activity(json_body["activityName"], json_body)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.info(str(e.__class__.__name__))

        return 'fail'

    return 'success'


main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

I expected for the logged class name to be TypeError but instead it was just Excpetion. Hence I was unable to create my own custom Exceptions like below and catch these exceptions in order to handle them accordingly.

```
class DownloadError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.code)
```

```
try:
   # call function activity
 except DownloadError as e:
    return {"errorCode": e.code}
 except LoginError as e:
   # some retry logic
 except Exception as e:
    return {"errorCode": 0}
```

However the only documentation I can see for catching Exceptions in the orchestrator doesn't specify Exception Types so I don't know if what I was trying to do is possible

Comment: In order to catch exceptions in a Durable Function, you can use the try-catch block inside the activity function itself. If an exception is raised in the activity function, it is propagated to the orchestrator, which can then catch it and handle it accordingly.

Comment: That's not what my question asked. You can see from my code snippets I am trying to return a specific Exception type to be handled in the orchestrator not just a generic exception

Comment: Also struggling with custom exception handlers in python azure df.